# In-house vs out-of-house

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests

What word or expression would you use to describe an employee who is contracted by a company on a project-by-project basis but who cannot be considered a freelancer as he or she works exclusively for this company? In other words, what'd you call a specialist who is not on the payroll, works from home, gets paid per project but is commited to one company? Is it possible to use the expression "an out-of-house specialist" to denote a staff member who is not an in-house employee but cannot be really considered a freelancer? Thanks.

Comment: Is this person contractually obligated to only work with the particular company? If not, then the fact that he/she works exclusively with the company seems incidental to the nature of their relationship, and not relevant.

Comment: Well, let's assume it doesn't matter whether such an agreement was formal or not. Perhaps, an "outsourced specialist/manager/whatever-they-do" could do the trick?

Comment: In that case, I usually hear "outsourced," "consultant" and "contractor" used interchangeably.

Comment: Thanks. I was kind of confused by the relatively high number of matches in Google, especially in the UK, and thought this expression was used as a regular antonym to "in-house".

Answer (score 4):

I would never use "an out-of-house specialist". Contractor is a better term to use in this situation.

Comment: Thanks. How would you elaborate this so as to show that the person is question is a regular contractor?

Comment: I can only speak for the USA, but a person who has a contract with a company (1099) would be called a "Contractor" I wouldn't distinguish between a "contractor" and a "regular contractor" Does that answer the question?

Comment: +1 Also *contract employee*. Some work categories use a specific term such as *contract lawyer*.

Answer (score 1):

In Cambridge dictionary, in-house means "Something that is done in-house is done within an organization or business by its employees rather than by other people". 
For example, "All our advertising material is designed in-house."

Out-house means "if an employee of a company works out of house, they work from home rather than in the offices of that company".
For example, "Many of our project team-members are based out of house."

Answer (score 0):

You could call them a 'consultant'.

Comment: Well, what if their services do not have to do anything with consulting? I dunno... let's assume they do exactly the same job as the in-house personnel, only they don't have any set working hours and get paid per assignment.

Comment: I'm not sure you have to define their life by a single label.

Comment: You don't have to but they may need to call themselves one way or another in their CVs, lol. Anyway, do you find this word choice awkward? I'm asking, because I've found quite a lot of matches in Google but I wonder whether it sounds too frivolous, vulgar or plain wrong.